# How to unit test Vue component that uses Axios (or other async update)?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, axios, jestjs

I have a Vue component/view that performs an API request using Axios and updates the component data with the response. I'm using Moxios to mock the Axios request in unit tests.

I tried using `Vue.nextTick` to postpone assertion of the updated data, but the component has not updated at that point yet.  If I add a delay, the assertion works correctly:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch('Updated text')
    done()
}, 500)
```

However this is bad practice, slows down the tests and is a race condition.

Is there some kind of assertion check that would be called every time a component updates?  Essentially, I'm looking for something like:

```
Vue.eventually(() => {
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch('Updated text')
    done()
})
```

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test that the async operation updates the component correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A generic (non-Vue-specific) workaround:

```
const test = () => {
    try {
        expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch('Updated text')
        done()
    } catch (e) {
        setTimeout(test, 1)
    }
}
setTimeout(test, 1)
```

However, any failures from the `expect` are ignored and the test times out without any message if failing.